# Is it possible to do string concatenation on list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to concatenate even index strings and odd index strings with just a list comprehension, the code looks like this but, is all wrong !

```
s = input()
[even+=item if index%2 == 0 else odd+=item for index,item in enumerate(s)]
```

Obviously the code gives me a invalid syntax error.

I would like to know if someone could help me by telling me if it is possible to do that by a list comprehension.

Thanks !

Comment: @Chris The question is quite self-explanatory. What would change if you know the sample input? The answer is still negative.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a list comprehension? You are not trying to create a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible (at least in Python < 3.8). Anyway, slicing would be more efficient than list comprehension (and *possible*, too):

```
even, odd = s[::2], s[1::2]
```

Incidentally, it runs ~100x faster than two separate list comprehensions for odd and even characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I would like to know if there is any handbook to learn list comprehension more deep.

Answer (score -2):

If you keep even and odd in the same list it will be a big list of both values, differentiate them b "even" and "odd" and then use it as you want

The correct syntax to your code  would be :

```
even, odd ="",""
odd = [odd+item for index,item  in enumerate(s) if index%2!=0 ]
even = [even+item for index,item  in enumerate(s) if index%2==0 ]
print(''.join(even))
print(''.join(odd))
```

without List comprehension :

```
for index,item in enumerate(s):
     if (index%2==0):
          even=even+item
     else:
         odd=odd+item
print(even)
```

For more info on List Comprehension  examples:
Please look at :
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Comment: There is no point in having the initial ``even`` and ``odd`` variables, nor adding them to ``item``. Selecting even/odd indices can be done more efficiently using slicing, either via ``[::2]`` or ``itertools.islice(None, None, 2)``.